# How to use Python to convert .r8 image files to .ppm?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert .r8 files to ppm files using a python scrpit.
The scrpit works when converting .jpg files, but doesn't seem to work with .r8 files.

```
import PIL.Image
import os, os.path, string, sys


openfile = '/Users/.../.../Image_converter'
im = PIL.Image.open('Test0.r8')
im = im.convert('RGB')
im.save('Test0.ppm')
im.show('Test0.ppm')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R8_to_PPM.py", line 7, in <module>
    im = PIL.Image.open('Test0.r8')
  File "/Users/FirstDawn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2286, in open
% (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file 'Test0.r8'
```

Is there anyway to make this conversion using python? (Or another language?)
I'm using python 2.7 on a MacOS. (.r8 = raw graphics (one byte per pixel) plane one (PicLab))
Thank you.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the r8 image file format, do you have a link to more information?  Is this just a raw image file with no header?  Do you know the image size?

Comment: I have not found a lot of detailed information regarding the .r8 extension. This site (http://filext.com/file-extension/R8 ) expands a bit to say "RAW Graphic FileRaw graphics (one byte per pixel) plane one (PicLab). A raw image file (sometimes written RAW image file) contains minimally processed data from the image sensor of a digital camera or image scanner. Raw files are so named because they are not yet processed and ready to be used with a bitmap graphics editor or printed.”

Comment: The README in the astrophysical code HARM states that "R8 is an unmapped format of 1-bit in "color" depth.  R8 images are smaller in size since they do not provide the color scheme.  Their downside is that after generating the R8 images, one must convert them to PPM or some other format with a user-supplied parsing program."

Comment: @ilent2 This is the information from the header:
RAW
# t=     6.00257055895168 nstep=297 vartype= 1  whichpl= 0 scale= 1 limits= 0 aa=0.00499921 lmin=7.87204e-05 lmax=51208 
128 64 
255 (total size)

Comment: You could try writing a parser that reads the header, extracts the total size, and then writes a PPM header with the size to a new file followed by the image data.

Comment: @ilent2 I'm not familiar with parsers.  Could you give an example or suggest some links please? Thank you.